# ¿Como puedo hacer un slider en android?

Tags: android, recyclerview, slider

*Hola amigos quisiera saber como puedo hacer un slider en android junto a un lista hecha con un recyclerview y se deslice con esta*

**Ejemplo de la app de mercado libre, slider(Rojo) y lista(azul):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias tomar como base esto: http://www.sanktips.com/2017/07/09/how-to-make-image-slider-with-viewpager-in-android-studio/

Comment: Trata lo que comenta Tegito123 y vuelve a preguntar si tienes problemas al realizarlo.

Comment: Gracias lo intentare